# How to incorporate Win UI with Prism across the Uno platform?

Tags: prism, uno-platform, winui-3

I fetched the **Prism Blank App (Uno Platform)** template to set up a basic `PrismApplication` in the shared project. Probably a very good reason, it is a blank template, therefore even the **Win UI Desktop** project is missing from the solution. By default this template employs the UWP API instead of the Win UI one as the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` namespace. I tried to create another solution with the Win UI specific Uno Platform template but in that case I failed to swap `Application` with `PrismApplication`.

Which template do you recommend to kick off, the first or the latter?

1. Created Win UI & Wasm heads

   `$dotnet new unoapp-winui -o "Weather.History" -uwp=false -ios=false -android=false -macos=false -sw=false -sg=false`
2. Swapped the base class

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Post your attempt and any exceptions or errors you might have not able to figure out.

Comment: @mxmissile, do you know another framework alike that can fusion with the Uno Platform ? I do not insist on having this particular one, merely seek a neat ctor injection and a messaging mechanism to let the view-models small talk.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @l33t yes, as Prism 8.1 was released they published the respective nugets for each platform.